# does asp mvc model size affect performance

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I've been developing a website and instead of having lots of models i've been chaining properties and what not to a single model by populating a prop and returning itself. not very important to the question but

```
var data = model.withUser(user).withStuff(data)
```

i'm curious if having a model class with a lot of lines of code will affect performance of the web app?

Thoughts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well yes... more code to run == more execution time yet we are talking micro and mostly likely nano seconds of time here.

If you are worried about that you are either A. Facebook or B. Google.  ;)

Comment: it's not more code to run in my scenario. i only use a few props from the class in each view. I guess I was thinking more about webforms and viewstate and if mvc model class size could affect performance the way viewstate did in webforms.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about performance (you'd have to benchmark one approach versus the other to say for sure), but I can say that having one monolithic class is going to be a pain when it comes to testing and reasoning about how it works.

In general, [prefer composition to inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance) (lots of small classes to one large class).

Comment: thanks for the comment, but i can't mark this as an answer since you don't answer the question.